# ProvidesPackage with semantic versionning

Tags: package-writing

I uploaded (right before TexLive 2024's freeze :-( ) a package, switching to semantic versioning like:

```
\ProvidesPackage{zx-calculus}[v2.2 A package to typeset ZX calculus and circuits directly in LaTeX, based on tikz/tikzcd.]
```

but I just realized that this causes a bug (`ERROR: Missing = inserted for \ifnum.`, this was not cached by my tests since I `\input` the `.sty` file because it lies in a different folder), and that `v2.2` should be replaced by `2024/03/15` instead…

I thought that this field was actually free-form, but seems like it is not. So 3 questions:

1. does that mean that semantic versioning cannot be done in LaTeX?
2. since TexLive 2024's froze was a few days ago, is it to late to upgrade the package to include a package that can actually be loaded without errors?
3. would it be possible to add some tests on CTAN to avoid such easy mistakes?

Comment: The release version of texlive24 was frozen, not texlive24. It will be updated continuously with new package versions from ctan until spring next year.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need the date first, you can use either `/` or `-`  then a space, then the following is free text but typically starts with a version string in whatever form you want.

If you upload the fix to ctan it will be distributed to texlive 2024 uses via `tlmgr` in the usual way.

The initial iso is now what it is. In previous years that would have been used to burn thousands of DVD posted to members of tex user groups so having errors on that was inconvenient, but now it really doesn't matter much: it's just a snapshot in time.

Note you should never `\input` a package, even for testing, didn't you get warnings from that?

Comment: Thanks a lot! But most linux distributions would package texlive's released snapshot I guess, no? I don't remember seing any warning, but note that it is a tikz library, so I input the `.code.tex` file. I don't know any much better solution since the documentation is in a subfolder `doc/somefile.tex` while the `.sty` is at the root folder.

Comment: @tobiasBora oh if you input the code.tex not the .sty then my comment doesn't apply (but if you are testing from latex why not use `\usepackage` ? the linux distributions don't always take the first day's version of texlive -xxxx and even if they do they do roll out updates via apt or rpm or whatever (not on the daily updates of upstream texlive but not frozen for a year)

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot! Ok good then… but how would you `\usepackage` a file in a different directory (ideally without requiring me to setup environment variables/latexmk…)? Doing `\usepackage{../foo}` does not work.

Comment: `\usepacke{../../name}` would work (just moan about the package name) but when testing packages I either use the current directory or I use a local texmf tree so that normall calls can be tested (`l3build` for example will handle such requirements automatically) @tobiasBora

Comment: Hum, actually I remember now I think, the problem with this is that since it is a tikz package, it will complain that the `.code.tex` file cannot be found (since that one is also in a different folder). Regarding `l3build`, I could, but I was just lazy to setup it since I need to find how to integrate it with emacs, choose whether I want to run it once or with latexmk etc… while `\input` is very simple… but seems like it has its own drawbacks as I just experienced.

Comment: I wouldn't expect a `.code.tex` file to have `\ProvidesPackage`: the pattern is generally that's present in a `.sty` even for TikZ bundles with a `.code.tex` file also

Comment: You aren't really supposed to use a path in `\usepackage`: the file should one way or another be in the input tree (current dir, local `texmf` tree, `TEXINPUTS`, ...)